# .NET Core/Standard: unable to install Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, .net-core, nuget

Using:
[image: Visual Studio Community 2019 v16.9.4]

Unable to install **Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk** (in .NET Core/Standard project for unit testing), getting this following error:
[image: Unable to find package 'microsoft.net.test.sdk' at source '']

I can install other packages, like **NUnit** and **NUnit3TestAdapter**.

I have the following package sources configured:
[image: Package Sources]

Answer (score 0):

Moved the packages I needed from other computer on different network. Seems to be a network issue.